# What kind of Windows-based "process accounting" software is available?

Tags: windows-7, memory-usage, cpu-usage, disk-space-utilization, process-accounting

Linux has pacct and kernel-based processing.  What equivalents are available for Windows?  I am aware (and use/recommend) of Process Explorer, but that only tracks real-time stats, with non-portable graphs for a single process.  I want to be able to track CPU, Memory, I/O for all of my processes on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Performance Monitor does have the ability to do what you're looking for, just not with realtime graphing. Since you tagged this [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) you have access to the full tool for this.

1. Open "Performance Monitor"
2. Expand "Data Collector Sets"
3. Expand "User Defined"
4. Right-click, select New
5. Use "Manually Defined"
6. Select "Performance Counter" but nothing else.
7. Add the relevant process-level monitors you need

   1. Click Add.
   2. Find "Process"
   3. Look for the items you need
   4. In the "Instances" dropdown, select "" for everything, and click Add.
   5. Repeat as needed.
   6. Click Finished when done.
8. Right-click on the monitor you just created, and go to Properties.
9. Go to the "Stop Condition" tab to specify how long you want to monitor.
10. To start monitoring, right-click on the monitor and select start. Stop the same way if you want to stop it before the stop-condition.

To view the report once monitoring is complete, it will be under Reports.

That'll get you started.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up digging around and find this one later on.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc709422

look at the "wpr"

can be kinda hardcore....

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how detailed you need to get either Perfmon or Windows Perfomance analyzer (from the performance toolkit) can provide these details.  In general it's best to have some sort of reason for this type of analysis on a desktop, for the server environment you can use all of the above as well as windows system resource manager to do accounting.